# Internet radio in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, internet-radio

I have database with urls of internet radio stations, but i don't know how to play stream that I am suppose to get from url. I am working in asp.net mvc2. I would be grateful if anyone can direct me to solution or give me a link to some kind of tutorial.

Comment: I don't know if this is a difficult question or maybe I've didn't explained right. I need some guidelines. Any kind of help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply add windows media player control for desktop app, or HTML tag that contains that control, then using URl property set ur URL to the control and play .... try it with sth simple and URL with MMS protocol at the beginning instead

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side problem. The easiest way is to use Flash to play the stream.